# How to render Amp ads without amp-ad?

Tags: google-chrome, adsense, amp-html, amp-ad

Tried implementing amp-ad to render video ads in amp pages, but facing below issue.

```
<div class='ad-banner' id="div-gpt-ad-xxxxxxxxx-1">
<amp-ad layout=fluid height=fluid type="doubleclick" data-slot="/12431234343/Qa/Android_Mobile_Web/Home" json="{&quot;targeting&quot;:{&quot;NativeType&quot;:&quot;videoad&quot;}}">
</amp-ad>
```

In ad response we could see the proper response, but in elements we could see height=0 or hidden attrb has been added as part of amp-ad element. So rendered ad is not visible in the front end.

So is there anyway to render ad without amp-ads or the above one is resolvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout type of `fluid` isn't valid per the `amp-ad` [component specifications](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad), you require `fill`, `fixed`, `fixed-height`, `flex-item`, `intrinsic`, `nodisplay`, or `responsive`. Also you need to define a `height` and `width` value for your advertisement on the amp-ad element depending on the layout type selected.

From the amp-ad documentation:

> The `<amp-ad>` requires width and height values to be specified
>   according to the rule of its layout type. It requires a type argument
>   that select what ad network is displayed.

It's likely that the combination of these issues is causing the advertisement to hide.